# Python/Tensorflow (images must have either 3 or 4 dimensions)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Hi so I have already done the object detection training and everything goes well until I tried to test it on images. I am using jupyter notebook. So far, I cant find any solution in here. Thanks!

```
img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
image_np = np.array(img)
image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np_expanded, dtype=tf.float32)
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
              for key, value in detections.items()}
detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

# detection_classes should be ints.
detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np_with_detections,
            detections['detection_boxes'],
            detections['detection_classes'] + label_id_offset,
            detections['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=8,
            min_score_thresh=5,
            agnostic_mode=False)

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_np_with_detections, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

**This is the code ^**

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16652/4271426025.py in 
4
5 input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np_expanded, dtype=tf.float32)
----> 6 detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
7
8 num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))

C:\imtired\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
151     except Exception as e:
152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
154     finally:
155       del filtered_tb

C:\imtired\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
1130             else:
1131               raise

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "C:\Users\Jayley\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16652/3600898474.py", line 11, in detect_fn  *
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
File "C:\imtired\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\meta_architectures\ssd_meta_arch.py", line 484, in preprocess  *
    normalized_inputs, self._image_resizer_fn)
File "C:\imtired\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\utils\shape_utils.py", line 492, in resize_images_and_return_shapes  *
    outputs = static_or_dynamic_map_fn(
File "C:\imtired\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\utils\shape_utils.py", line 246, in static_or_dynamic_map_fn  *
    outputs = [fn(arg) for arg in tf.unstack(elems)]
File "C:\imtired\TFODCourse\tfod\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\core\preprocessor.py", line 3327, in resize_image  *
    new_image = tf.image.resize_images(

ValueError: 'images' must have either 3 or 4 dimensions.
```

Comment: img = io.imread('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png')

Comment: Can you try with a sample image?

Comment: Remove `image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)` will fix this issue. Please take a look at similar issue https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9978